# c++ delimiting text file with inverted commas followed by commas

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, text

I've got a text file that looks like this:

```
123,removed inc,2006, removed,"1,021,000.16",0.0,
U2123,removed Inc,2006, removed,"21,600.00",13.10,123
A721,removed Inc,2604, removed,"21,600.10",103.00,
U2122,removedInc,2612, removed,"21,600.00",0
U1123,removed corp,2612, removed,"21,600.00",13.10,
U3123,removed Inc,2006, removed,"69,600.01","18,200.00",A721, U2123,U2122,123,U2q,U211193
U211193,removed Inc,2615,removed,"1,821,600.00",13.10
```

And I need to store it in a vector in the c++ program. Now noting that extracting and storing data in a vector where the data is delimited by commas, has been covered a lot in these forums. However, in the cases above were the comma is actually inside the integer, using this method doesn't work. I'm thinking that in the case after the comma there is a ", then the whole number would be stored and not delimited at the comma in the value however, i can't figure out what the best way

This is my current code:

```
void readFile()
{
    string fileName = "Data1.txt";
    
    ifstream myFile(fileName);

    // vector set to be type 'account'
    // parsing each line into the vector. read across and thinking about what defines i.e "" or , .

    string line;
    getline (myFile, line);
        
    int i = 0;
        while (getline(myFile,line))
    {
            cout << "line" << ++i << "is:" << line << endl;

            // this is pseudo code and where i need help
            if (str[0] != '/') 
            { something* something = parseLine(line); 
            
            rsult.push_back(something); }
        }

            
    }       
}
```

Comment: You're not showing your current `parseLine` code, but you'll notice that the values with embedded commas are in quotes, so you basically need a toggle flag, `inQuotes` that you set or reset when a quote is seen. Only commas encounted when `inQuotes` is false should be consider field delimiters.

Comment: If all your numbers are always guaranteed to be inside the quotation marks, per each line you can: find pattern \".+\" and remove it from the line, split modified line to vector of strings, replace empty string in your vector with the previously found string.

Comment: Thanks guys, still largely lost but will continue to get through it! cheers

Comment: Did you meanwhile find `std::quoted`?  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted